# how to display the information that related to a specific user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i have this Model

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and this view

```
def view_profile(request):
    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    shippingAddress = ShippingAddress.objects.all()
    args = {'user': request.user, 'cartItems': cartItems, 'shippingAddress': shippingAddress}
    return render(request, 'store/profile.html', args)
```

template

```
{% for sa in shippingAddress %}
        <p>address: {{ sa.address }}</p>
        <p>city: {{ sa.city }}</p>
        <p>state: {{ sa.state }}</p>
        <p>zipcode: {{ sa.zipcode }}</p>


        {% endfor %}`enter code here`
```

the problem is the template display all the Shipping Addresses in the DB and i want it just to display the Shipping Address that related to the **signed in user**

Thanks

Comment: How does the `Customer` relates to the user? Furthermore the modeling here allows to have *multiple* `ShippingAddress`es for one `Customer` (and likely also multiple `Customer`s for one `User`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to query the Customer model first:

```
active_customer = Customer.objects.get(name=request.user)
```

Next, you need to set a reverse relation in your "ShippingAddress" model, something similar to:

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="shipping_address")
```

Once this is set you can get all shipping addresses for the queried customer:

```
shipping_addresses = active_customer.shipping_address.all()
```

Pass them to the context and iterate them in the template to display them. Note that the Customer query might be different as it depends on how the Customer model is set.